# Flair font color unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image]
[image]

The default and clean theme for [user flairs](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/flair) have unreadable font colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the default link color in this setting to `#888E84` which is based on the physics logo color.